# Removing author auto generated javadoc in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

How do you remove the auto generated author javadoc in NetBeans.

I've already removed this in the templates for everything I use, but, still, when I type a brand new javadoc at the beginning of a class, it generates code like this:

```
/**
*
* @author username
*/
```

When I would like for it to just be like so:

```
/**
*
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can to to Tools > Templates > Java > Java Class > Open in Editor

It will show something like:

```
/**
 *
 * @author ${user}
 */
public class ${name} {

}
```

Simply change that to:

```
/**
 *
 */
public class ${name} {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to disable that in the code completion of /**, not in the templates

Comment: Why to keep those three asterisks!? Anyway, I got the point. Now it's clean.